# Finding out Last logon time in Windows through Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, scripting

How do you find out the last log-in time for a windows machine(any user) through powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's apparently [non-trivial](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/07/18/finding-the-latest-logon-time/) when you involve domain controllers.  Here's the code ripped from that blog entry (first one on google, by the way)

Without a Domain Controller:

```
(Get-QADUser username).lastLogon
```

With:

```
Get-QADComputer -ComputerRole
DomainController | foreach {
(Get-QADUser -Service $_.Name
-SamAccountName username).LastLogon.Value } |
Measure-Latest
```

Comment: Thanks Tom Ritter. I saw that one too before raising this question on SO. But my question is about last login time for any user on a machine (I'm not concerned about one particular user)

Comment: Doesn't work with Powershell 3.0. Error is: Get-QADComputer : "The term 'Get-QADComputer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"